# Save workspace variable in multiple excel files

Tags: excel, matlab

I am having lot of text files. The data in each file is in the format '511E7D7C:13,IIMWV,023,R,18.5,M,A*1D~05';
I want third and fifthcolumn. For that i used textscan and saved that data in separate  variable. As i am having multiple files in directory, I have run for loop and I want to save those variables in excel files in the loop. Im using eval and xlswrite but it is not working. Please guide me if any one knows the correct answer.
 Here is the code:

```
enter code here
files = dir('*.txt');    
for i = 1:numel(files);    
filename = files(i).name;    
fid = fopen(filename);
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s','delimiter',',');
variable1 = C{1,3};
eval9['xlswrite vdr' num2str(i) ' variable1']);
end
```

Comment: Why is it not working? Does it die silently? Do you get an error message? If yes, please post it.

Comment: Instead of data in the variable, name of the variable 'var1' is saving.